# Absolute Galois Group of $\mathbb{R}(t)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let us consider the field of rational functions in one variable with real coefficients, $\mathbb{R}(t)$. The algebraic closure is the field of algebraic functions with real coefficients. What is known of the absolute galois group here? Can we say anything, and if sp, what?

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraic functions with real coefficients"? It doesn't sound like it includes $i$.

Comment: The function f(x)=i is algebraic, it satisfies the equation x^2+1. So all functions satisfying an algebraic equations with real polynomial coefficients are there.

Comment: Replace polynomial coefficients with rational functions :)

Comment: @ChrisEagle See the [wiki article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function).

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206362

Comment: @JSchlather Do you know of any source proving that the algebraic functions are algebraically closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of cardinality of $\kappa$. Then the absolute Galois group of $k(t)$ is the free profinite group $\hat{F}_\kappa$ on $\kappa$ generators. See [here](http://msp.org/pjm/2000/196-2/p12.xhtml).

So in your case we have that the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb R(t)$ is $\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \rtimes \hat{F}_\kappa$. Since the absolute Galois group will be generated by complex conjugation and the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb C(t)$.

Comment: This blew my mind the first time I saw it.

Comment: Dear @JSchlather, Let $E$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(t)$. Since $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{R}(t)$ of degree $2$,  $G(E/\mathbb{C}(t))$ is a normal open subgroup of $G(E/\mathbb{R}(t))$ of index $2$. In particular, the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\ltimes \hat{F}_k$, no?